# Hadoop sample map reduce program using Awk

Tags: hadoop, awk, mapreduce

I am familiar with Hadoop using Java. Looking for sample Hadoop Map reduce program using AWK only.

For a text file containing...

```
A k1
B k1
C k2
D k3
```

Looking for an o/p

```
k1 2
k2 1
k3 1
```

Comment: It seems unlikely you'll find someone who is both an awk expert AND a "Hadoop Map reduce" expert (whatever that is!). You showed sample input and expected output and asked for an awk script to perform that transformation but then rejected @sudo_0's answer that does exactly that. Not sure where you expect things to go from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise using Hadoop streaming to do this. I'm not a Awk expert by any means, but using @sudo_O answer and transforming it into the Hadoop world here is what I would do:

1. Write an Awk script that will be used as your mapper. You need only a mapper for this, no need for reducers.

   ```
   $ cat mapper.awk
   #!/usr/bin/awk -f

   {a[$2]++}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}
   ```
2. You can run your Hadoop streaming job doing the following:

   ```
   ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop \
   jar ${HADOOP_HOME}/contrib/streaming/*.jar \
   -D mapreduce.job.reduces=0 \
   -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
   -input /path/to/input.txt \
   -output /path/to/output/dir \
   -mapper mapper.awk \
   -file /path/to/mapper.awk
   ```
3. You can view the results in HDFS by doing:

   ```
   hadoop fs -cat /path/to/output/dir/*
   ```

Answer (score 4):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk '{a[$2]++}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' file
k1 2
k2 1
k3 1
```

Comment: I know nothing about `Hadoop`.. I know how to perform text transformations using `awk`. The `awk` script given takes your example input and maps it to your example output, which is what you asked for. If this is not what you was looking for please edit your question clearly stating the problem.

Comment: I wanted to run it on cluster containing multiple data nodes.. I have clearly specified "hadoop map reduce program using awk"

Comment: You also clearly specify `I am familiar with Hadoop using Java`.. here is the `awk` code you asked for, go use it with your `Hadoop` environment.